# Select de horário no MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Boa tarde galera! tudo bem?

Estou desenvolvendo um plugin que puxa de um banco de dados os programas de televisão, ele deveria puxar pelo horário e mostrar em uma tabela os programas que estão passando ao vivo, de acordo com o horário do sistema (horário atual) e só trocar quando começar o outro programa.

atualmente meu select é assim:

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(horario, '%H:%i') as horario FROM wp_grade, 
(SELECT horario AS a FROM wp_grade WHERE horario <= '$gh_data' order by horario DESC LIMIT 1) AS b WHERE horario >=a ORDER BY horario
```

Esse select funciona apenas para o horário, porém não leva em consideração a data (dia, mês e ano).

a tabela é assim:

```
create table wp_grade(
id int primary key,
programa varchar(50),
descricao text,
horario datetime);
```

qual alteração deveria fazer?

Comment: Testar se a data que consta na grade é igual à data do sistema. No seu caso a parte de data de seu campo datetime `horario`. Utilize a função `DATE(horario) = CURRENT_DATE`.

Answer (score 1):

Segue abaixo um exemplo:

[Exemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b8567e/1)

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(horario, '%H:%i') as horario FROM wp_grade, 
(SELECT horario AS a FROM wp_grade WHERE DATE(horario) = CURRENT_DATE 
 order by horario DESC LIMIT 1) AS b 
 WHERE horario >= a ORDER BY horario
```

Comment: Olá! então, continua dando o mesmo problema :( Ele consegue ordenar por horário, porém não leva a data (dia, mês e ano) em conta. Por exemplo, se tem o programa do ratinho no dia 02/12/2020 as 00:15 e o programa da Eliana no dia 02/12/2019 as 0:30 ele vai aparecer o programa do ratinho e não da eliana.